# Creating this minimization function

Tags: r

I have a sample S with predictor vectors Xs and Binary responses Ys. I would like to create the following function:

[image: formula]

Basically, for a given X_i it gives me the minimum of the l2 norm of its difference from observations with a different outcome. I know that you can probably create a function that just loops over all the differences one by one. But I wonder if there's some vectorized way?

My attempt:

The data set is n by p+1, n = sample size, p = # predictors, Y as last row:

```
g <- vector();
for(i in 1:n){
   temp <- t(data[data$Y[i] != data$Y, 1:p]) - as.vector(t(data[i,1:p]))
   g[i]<- min(col.norm(temp))
}
```

Comment: Hi! StackOverflow does not visualise latex, you may use [this](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) as a workaround (copy-paste the resulting formula). Please correct your formula since right now it is not readable. Also please provide your best attempt for your function (either vectorized or not). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I've fixed the formula and also added my own attempt now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how big is your data. I guess you want to vectorise in order to optimise for performance. Here you have a possible solution using `slqdf`.

(I looked for alternatives like `data.table` but I did not succeed to perform a cartesian product with your condition that Y != Y on each side of the join...)

First I create a toy dataframe and run it with your code.

```
library(tilting)
data <- data.frame(p1=seq(1, 6), p2=seq(12, 17), p3=seq(14,9), Y=c(rep(0,3), rep(1,3)))
g <- vector();
n <- nrow(data)
p <- 3
for(i in 1:n){
  temp <- t(data[data$Y[i] != data$Y, 1:p]) - as.vector(t(data[i,1:p]))
  g[i]<- min(col.norm(temp))
}
```

Where the result for g is,

```
[1] 5.196152 3.464102 1.732051 1.732051 3.464102 5.196152
```

Then I add an index to the data using `rownames` and perform the cartesian product,

```
data$idx <- rownames(data) 
library(sqldf)
predictors <- c("p1", "p2", "p3")
cart <- sqldf(paste0("select d1.idx,", 
                     paste("d1", predictors, collapse=",", sep="."), ",",
                     paste("d2", predictors, collapse=",", sep="."),
                     " from data as d1",
                     " join data as d2",
                     " on d1.Y != d2.Y"))
```

Then I calculate your function,

```
cart$d <- sqrt(rowSums((cart[, 2:4] - cart[, 5:7])^2))
```

and minimising is just like aggregating results.

```
> aggregate(cart, by=list(cart$idx), FUN=min)[, c("idx", "d")]
  idx        d
1   1 5.196152
2   2 3.464102
3   3 1.732051
4   4 1.732051
5   5 3.464102
6   6 5.196152
```

As I said, not sure of your objective, but I hope it helps.